# The measurability in a proof of Doob’s martingale maximal inequalities

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, martingales

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $M=(M_t, t\ge 0)$ a continuous martingale with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal F_t, t\ge 0)$. Let $T>0, \lambda >0$, and $p \ge 1$.

I'm reading a proof of below theorem from [this](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/lecture-11-doobs-martingale-maximal-inequalities/) link.

> **Theorem** If $\mathbb E [ |M_T|^p] < \infty$ then
> $$
> \mathbb P \bigg [ \sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| \ge \lambda \bigg ] \le \frac{\mathbb E [ |M_T|^p ]}{ \lambda^p}.
> $$

**Proof** For $p \ge 1$, the map $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex. It follows from $\mathbb E [ |M_T|^p] < \infty$ and Jensen's inequality that $(|M_t|^p, t \in [0, T])$ is a sub-martingale w.r.t. $(\mathcal F_t, t\ge 0)$. Let
$$
\tau := T \wedge \inf \{t \ge 0 :  |M_t| \ge \lambda\}.
$$

Then $\tau$ is a stopping time w.r.t. $(\mathcal F_t, t\ge 0)$ such that $\tau \le T$. By Doob’s optional stopping theorem for a sub-martingale,
$$
\mathbb E [|M_{\tau}|^p] \le \mathbb E [|M_{T}|^p].
$$

By definition of $\tau$,
$$
\begin{align}
|M_{\tau}|^p &= |M_{\tau}|^p 1_{\{\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| \ge \lambda\}} + |M_{\tau}|^p 1_{\{\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| < \lambda\}} \\
&\ge \lambda^p 1_{\{\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| \ge \lambda\}} + |M_T|^p 1_{\{\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| < \lambda\}}.
\end{align}
$$

Thus
$$
\mathbb P \bigg [ \sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| \ge \lambda \bigg ] \le \frac{\mathbb E [|M_T|^p 1_{\{\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| \ge \lambda\}}]}{\lambda^p} \le \frac{\mathbb E [|M_T|^p]}{\lambda^p}.
$$

---

**My understanding** Let $(X_t, t \in [0, T])$ be a stochastic process. Then $\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |X_t|$ is not necessarily Borel measurable because $[0, T]$ is uncountable. Let $(t_n, n \in \mathbb N)$ be a dense subset of $[0, T]$. Because $M$ has continuous paths,
$$
\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t| = \sup_n  |M_{t_n}|.
$$

The supremum over a countable collection of Borel measurable functions is again Borel measurable. So $\sup_{t \in [0, T]} |M_t|$ is Borel measurable.

> Could you confirm if my above understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes, it it certainly correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much for your verification!